# Voice command using asp.net c# (no win-form please)

Tags: c#, asp.net, speech-recognition, voice

I want to use voice activated commands on my website. I have already implemented it on win forms using `System.Speech.Recognition`. However can't manage to use it on web application. Example code snippet would be appreciated.

Can I use it with web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have voice activated commands on your website, but it'll probably be difficult to refactor you winforms code. There are many articles around, so I suggest you google around a little bit further. You have the choice: you can go for the server-side route or you can use client-side frameworks (or some hybrid approach).

Comment: i have searched already on google and found almost everything about win-form. those which are about asp.net either broken or don't work.

Comment: It's very hard to believe that. Here's an article from Ricardo Peres that covers this topic: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/speech-recognition-in-asp-net.

Comment: i already read it, and must admit found difficult to understand and impletment. however i tried and now getting this error. 'Error 3 'elearning._Default.ServerSpeechRecognitionProvider.RecognizeFromWav(string)': no suitable method found to override'

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the browser's built in Speech recognition capabilities. Chrome, for example, has [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API?hl=en) which can turn any input field into a speech-aware input field.